# Issue with running Node application in AWS ECS container

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, amazon-ecr

I have created a Docker image and pushed it to the AWS ECR repository

I'm creating a task with 3 containers included, one for Redis one for PostgreSQL and another one for the given Image which is my Node project

In Dockerfile, I have added a CMD to run the App with `node` command, here is the Dockerfile content:

```
FROM node:16-alpine as build

WORKDIR /usr/token-manager/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

FROM node:16-alpine as production

ARG ENV_ARG=production
ENV NODE_ENV=${ENV_ARG}

WORKDIR /usr/token-manager/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install --production

COPY --from=build /usr/token-manager/app/dist ./dist

CMD ["node", "./dist/index.js"]
```

This image is working in a docker-compose locally without any issue

The issue is when I run the task in ECS Cluster it's not running the Node project, it seems that it's not running the CMD command

I tried to override that CMD command by adding a new command to the Task definition:

[image]

When I run task with this command, there is nothing in the CloudWatch log and obviously the Node App is not running, here you can see that there is no log for `api-container`:

[image]

When I change the command to something else, for example "ls" it gets executed and I can see the result in CloudWatch log:

[image]

[image]

or when I change it to a wrong command, I get an error in the log:

[image]

But When I change it to the right command which should run the App, nothing happens, it's not even showing anything in the log as error

I have added inbound rules to allow the port number needed for connecting to the App but it seems it's not running at all!

What should I do? How can I check to see what is the issue?

**UPDATE**: I changed the App Container configuration to make it `Essential`, it means that the whole Task will fail and stop if this container exits with any error, then I started the Task again and it gets stopped, so now I'm sure that the App Container is crashing and exiting some how but there is nothing in the log!

Comment: Are you sure it is not running? Maybe it is running, it is just not logging (or the node process has different output)?

Comment: @MaciejRostański It's no accessible via IP and Port, I'm not sure if there is another log for Node App, I didn't find anything. I can see the logs for Redis and PostgreSQL in CloudWatch but nothing about my Node APP, the log configurations are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, I'll post it here, it may help someone else

If you go to Cluster details screen > Tasks tab > Stopped > Task ID, then you can see a brief status message regarding each container in Containers list:

[image]

it saying that container killed due to Memory issue, we can fix it by increasing the memory we specify for containers when adding new Task Definition

This is the total amount of memory you want to give to the whole Task, which will be shared between all containers:

[image]

When you are adding new Container, there is a place for specifying the memory limit:

[image]

***Hard Limit***: If you specify a Hard Limit, your container will get killed when attempt to exceed that limit of memory usage

***Soft Limit***: If you specify the Soft Limit, ECS will reserve that memory for your container, but your container can request more memory up to the Hard Limit

So the main point here is when there is some kind of Initial issue for container, there won't be any log in CloudWatch and when there is and issue but we didn't find anything in Log, then we should check possibilities like Memory or anything prevent container from being started

Answer (score 0):

First: Make Sure your Docker image in deployed to ECR(you can using Codepipeline) because that is where the ECS will look for the DockerImage.

Second:Please Specify your launch-Type, in case of Ec2 make sure you are using latest Node Image while adding container.
Here you can find latest Docker Image for Node: https://hub.docker.com/_/node

Third: Create Task-Definition and Run the task, now make sure you navigate to cluster and check if task is running and check task status.

Fourth: Make sure you allow all inbound traffic in Security group and open HTTP for 0.0.0.0/0

You can test using curl i.e :http://ec2-52-38-113-251.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com

In case you failed to do so, i would recommend deploying simple Node App and get that running and then deploy your project. Thank you